# Beamer \only<2> with lstlisting and tikz picture that references remember-nodes of the listing

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, listings, overlays

I use `TikZ`, `listings` and `Beamer` like this:

```
\defverbatim\modsecondcodeafter{%
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
// Iteriere 
for(i = 0 to N-1) {
   %\tikzmark{obbegin}%// Calculate indices
   $\ldots$ 
   // Calculate coefficient indices
   %\tikzmark{obend}%$\ldots$
   // Evaluate polynomial
   for(j = 0 to 19) {
      if(j == 0) {
         %\tikzmark{ibtarg}%
      }
      $\ldots$
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}  
}
   \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Codestructure sample modification}
      \modsecondcodeafter
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, thick]
      \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] ([shift={(-2pt,6pt)}]pic cs:obbegin) 
         -- ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:obend) 
            coordinate[midway,xshift=-6pt](Btip);

      \draw[->, rounded corners] (Btip) -- +(-4pt,0) |- (pic cs:ibtarg);
      \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
```

To get this output for the slide

[image]

But as soon as I add `\only<2>{ ... }` around the listing and TikZ picture, the picture is not displayed correctly anymore on slide 2

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

---

EDIT: Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\lstset{
   language=C++,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
   numbers=left,
   captionpos=b
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,tikzmark}
% This is the file main.tex
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\defverbatim\modsecondcodeafter{%
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
// Iterate
for(i = 0 to N-1) {
   %\tikzmark{obbegin}% // Calculate indices
   $\ldots$
   // Calculate coefficient indices
   %\tikzmark{obend}%$\ldots$
   // Evaluate polynomial
   for(j = 0 to 19) {
      if(j == 0) {
         %\tikzmark{ibtarg}%
      }
      $\ldots$
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}  
}
   \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Codestructure sample modification}
      \modsecondcodeafter
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, thick]
      \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] ([shift={(-2pt,6pt)}]pic cs:obbegin) 
         -- ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:obend) 
            coordinate[midway,xshift=-6pt](Btip);

      \draw[->, rounded corners] (Btip) -- +(-4pt,0) |- (pic cs:ibtarg);
      \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And minimal "not working" example (I only added `\only<2>{...}`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\lstset{
   language=C++,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
   numbers=left,
   captionpos=b
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,tikzmark}
% This is the file main.tex
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\defverbatim\modsecondcodeafter{%
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
// Iterate
for(i = 0 to N-1) {
   %\tikzmark{obbegin}% // Calculate indices
   $\ldots$
   // Calculate coefficient indices
   %\tikzmark{obend}%$\ldots$
   // Evaluate polynomial
   for(j = 0 to 19) {
      if(j == 0) {
         %\tikzmark{ibtarg}%
      }
      $\ldots$
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}  
}
   \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Codestructure sample modification}
      \only<2>{\modsecondcodeafter
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, thick]
      \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] ([shift={(-2pt,6pt)}]pic cs:obbegin) 
         -- ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:obend) 
            coordinate[midway,xshift=-6pt](Btip);

      \draw[->, rounded corners] (Btip) -- +(-4pt,0) |- (pic cs:ibtarg);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      }
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `\defverbatim` detour, you could use a `fragile` frame and directly put the `lstlisting` there. This can then be wrapped in an `onlyenv` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\lstset{
   language=C++,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
   numbers=left,
   captionpos=b
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,tikzmark}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Codestructure sample modification}

  \begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
// Iterate
for(i = 0 to N-1) {
   %\tikzmark{obbegin}% // Calculate indices
   $\ldots$
   // Calculate coefficient indices
   %\tikzmark{obend}%$\ldots$
   // Evaluate polynomial
   for(j = 0 to 19) {
      if(j == 0) {
         %\tikzmark{ibtarg}%
      }
      $\ldots$
   }
}
\end{lstlisting} 
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, thick]
      \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] ([shift={(-2pt,6pt)}]pic cs:obbegin) 
         -- ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:obend) 
            coordinate[midway,xshift=-6pt](Btip);

      \draw[->, rounded corners] (Btip) -- +(-4pt,0) |- (pic cs:ibtarg);
      \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{onlyenv}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, awesome. I guess the problem with `\only` is that it throws away the text on the first slide, so that tikz will not get the correct positions, or something like that? I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think this is combination of multiple problems -> hard to debug :)

Comment: Just a wild suggestion: create the same tikz nodes in other branches, i.e. in `\only<1>`, but leave them empty, so they _are_ there, but produce no visible output.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Sounds interesting, can you show a working example?

Comment: Sure. https://pastebin.com/0LrfUg5k I don't post it as an answer, as it does nothing with code listing.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Interesting trick, thanks for sharing! Might be useful to remember for future problems.